# Reinstalling Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: 13.10, reinstalling

I want to reinstall Ubuntu 13.10. After some adjustments, I eliminated some libraries left in black screen after login. So I decided to reinstall the operating system from a live CD. Will the data I had from my old user account remain intact as well as the applications that I had installed there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reinstall from the Live CD and not overwrite your *data* and *configurations* as long as you choose the correct options during installation. Make sure not to choose anything that says "**Format**". I think the option is "**Erase Ubuntu 13.10 and reinstall**".

You may have to re-install applications from the Ubuntu Software Center or sudo apt-get, but it shouldn't be difficult since most of it is free and available.

Also, you can view this answer for backing up your user-data to another folder so you can copy back what you need later: [Reinstalling Ubuntu without formating /home, as well as without any old config files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56051/reinstalling-ubuntu-without-formating-home-as-well-as-without-any-old-config-f)