# Using my Samsung Galaxy S5 to repair Ubuntu

Tags: boot, updates, smartphone

I updated from 14.02 to 14.04 and now I'm having issues with Grub. It only loads to a terminal style window. I've tried some of the options during reboot by holding shift during start up. Nothing there worked.

I'm wondering if it's possible to fix it using my phone? I don't have access to another computer. Thanks. :)

Comment: Try this: https://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/776643-how-to-rescue-a-non-booting-grub-2-on-linux/ I've messed up my grub once,too, used that tutorial to repair everything

Comment: Alternatively, use LiveCD/LiveUSB recovery : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCdRecovery There is described a process for failed update, but the idea is the same, `chroot` couple of folders, do `grub-install /dev/s**` (could be sda or sdb ), run `update-grub` and that should do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Open a text-only console by using the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>.
2. At the `login:` prompt type your username and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
3. At the `Password:` prompt type your user password and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
4. Now you are logged in to a text-only virtual console, and you can run terminal commands from the console, and repair Ubuntu locally from the console without using your smartphone. To reboot the system from the virtual console run the command: `sudo reboot`. Press the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> to exit from the console. In Ubuntu 17.10 and later press the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> to exit from the virtual console.
5. Try reading the answers to [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it).
6. If you can't follow the answers to [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it) you can reinstall Ubuntu from a DVD or USB flash drive by following the instructions in [Reinstalling Ubuntu 13.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/411264/reinstalling-ubuntu-13-10).
7. If you don't have an Ubuntu 14.04 live DVD or USB flash drive, there is an Android app called [DriveDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.softwarebakery.drivedroid). DriveDroid allows you to boot your PC from ISO/IMG files stored on your phone. This is ideal for trying Linux distributions without the need to burn different CDs or USB pendrives. The DriveDroid application requires root.

   DriveDroid also includes a convenient download menu where you can download USB images of a number of operating systems, including Ubuntu, Kubuntu, Xubuntu and Lubuntu, from your phone.

   [image]

   [image]

Comment: Problem is I don't know how to fix it from the terminal, which is why I'm looking to reinstall it. All the other fixes aren't working for me.

Comment: I appreciate the link as it has some options I hadn't tried, but they all fail. I'm trying to reinstall it but I can't burn a cd without my computer working. That's why I'm hoping I can do it from my S5. Download it directly and make it work.  Also I do appreciate your time.